# Socket.IO Chat not sending and/or recieving messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

I have followed a tutorial for socket.io chat:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNKNYLv2BpQ

In the tutorial video it works fine however mine does not work at all. The messages do not seem to be sent or received by either the server or the client

This is my app.js run on the server side with node

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('send message', function(data) {
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

This is my index.html client

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat with socket.io and node.js</title>
<style>
    #chat
    {
        height: 500px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chat"></div>
<form id="send-message">
    <input size="35" id="message"></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        var socket = io.connect();
        var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
        var $messageBox = $('#message');
        var $chat $('#chat');

        $messageForm.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val());
            $messageBox.val('');
        });

        socket.on('new message', function(data) {
            $chat.append(data + "<br/>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I suppose it is a simple error that I have overlooked but I'm stumped at the moment, any ideas ??? Also if you require additional information please say so :)

Comment: Try doing it this way, var io = require('socket.io')(server);

Comment: @NLN I get this when I try your solution: /home/snapper26/Desktop/chat/app.js:4
 io = require('socket.io')(server);
                          ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/snapper26/Desktop/chat/app.js:4:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3

Answer (score 0):

create one index.html file

**index.html**

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>


 <script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
</script>
```

**index.js**

```
 var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

[For more information click here](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)